# Get a list of files with full path

Tags: unix, ls

I would like to get a list of all the files in a directory hierarchy (like I would with `ls -R`), but such that instead of listing the name of the directory and its files beneath it, it would just output a list of files with their full path. Is this possible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `find` for this type of thing.

```
find /home/me/subdir
```

will list all the files and directories, with full path, that live in `/home/me/subdir`.

```
find /home/me/subdir -type f
```

will only list files. (`-type d` for directories.)

If you need to match a filename glob, do like this:

```
find /home/me/subdir -type f -name "abc*"
```

Or exclude a file name pattern:

```
find /home/me/subdir -type f ! -name ".*"
```

Comment: This also lists directories and hidden files. Any way to avoid that?

Comment: Edited with more examples. Please search this site, your favorite search engine, and the man page for additional options